# PERL SQL запрос

Tags: sql, perl

```
print Dumper $turu;
$VAR1 = [ '40', '41', '43', '44', '45' ];
```

Дампер показывает верные данные.
Делаю запрос

```
 my @items = ();
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM catn WHERE id IN (?)  ");
        my $rvs = $sth->execute($turu) or die "execute: ".$sth->errstr."\n";
        while (my $item = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) { 
            push(@items, $item);
        }
     $hash->{items} = \@items;
```

Пустота. Ответа нет.

Делаю запрос иначе - вставляю $turu сразу в запрос.

```
 my @items = ();
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM catn WHERE id IN ($turu)  ");
        my $rvs = $sth->execute() or die "execute: ".$sth->errstr."\n";
        while (my $item = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) { 
            push(@items, $item);
        }
     $hash->{items} = \@items;
```

Получаю ошибку execute: execute command denied to user 'name'@'%' for routine 'name.ARRAY'

Если в запрос просто подставить '40', '41', '43', '44', '45' - все работает, конечно.
Прав на сервере у меня нет, чтобы исправить command denied.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28168736/4496422

Answer (score 0):

Выше правильно подсказали, надо объеденить значения:

```
 my @items = ();
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM catn WHERE id IN (?)  ");
        my $rvs = $sth->execute(join(",", @$turu)) or die "execute: ".$sth->errstr."\n";
        while (my $item = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) { 
            push(@items, $item);
        }
     $hash->{items} = \@items;
```

Иначе в качестве значения прилетает ссылка на массив, сам запрос получается не корректным и возвращает пустое значение.